# Web application response message API

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-services, framework

The following excerpt is part of a web application microservice framework.
The goal of the provided module is to define a base class `Message` that may be configured by INI-style configuration files providing the message text in several languages. The code is limited to Python 3.4.

```
"""HIS web API messages."""

from configparser import ConfigParser

from flask import request

from wsgilib import JSON

__all__ = ['MessageNotFound', 'LanguageNotFound', 'Message']


class MessageNotFound(Exception):
    """Indicates that the respective message could not be found."""

    def __init__(self, message):
        """Sets the respective message."""
        super().__init__(message)
        self.message = message


class LanguageNotFound(Exception):
    """Indicates that the respective language could not be found."""

    def __init__(self, lang):
        """Sets the respective language."""
        super().__init__(lang)
        self.lang = lang


class MetaMessage(type):
    """Metaclass for messages."""

    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        """Reads and sets the message's respective locales."""
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        try:
            locales = cls.LOCALES
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        else:
            if isinstance(locales, str):
                cls.LOCALES = ConfigParser()
                cls.LOCALES.read(locales)

    @property
    def locales(cls):
        """Returns the message's locales."""
        try:
            return cls.LOCALES[cls.__name__]
        except KeyError:
            raise MessageNotFound(cls.__name__)


class Message(JSON, metaclass=MetaMessage):
    """Messages returned by the respective web application."""

    STATUS = 200

    def __init__(self, *data, status=None, **fields):
        """Initializes the message."""
        language = request.args.get('lang', 'de_DE')

        try:
            message = self.__class__.locales[language]  # Class property!
        except KeyError:
            raise LanguageNotFound(language)

        if status is None:
            status = self.__class__.STATUS

        if data:
            message = message.format(*data)

        dictionary = {'message': message}
        dictionary.update(fields)
        super().__init__(dictionary, status=status)
```

The super class of `Message`, `JSON`, is defined [here](https://gitlab.com/HOMEINFO/wsgilib/blob/9fbd4b9eedde6c700a49fa49b11151a9d9ef7762/wsgilib/responses.py#L117).

Example Usage in `account.py`:

```
"""Account related messages."""

from his.messages.api import Message

__all__ = [
    'NoAccountSpecified',
    'NoSuchAccount',
    'AccountLocked',
    'AccountCreated',
    'AccountDeleted',
    'AccountPatched',
    'NotAuthorized',
    'AccountExists',
    'AccountsExhausted',
    'PasswordTooShort']


class _AccountMessage(Message):
    """Abstract common account message."""

    LOCALES = '/etc/his.d/locale/his/account.ini'


class NoAccountSpecified(_AccountMessage):
    """Indicates that no account has been specified."""

    STATUS = 406


class NoSuchAccount(_AccountMessage):
    """Indicates that an account with the specified name does not exist."""

    STATUS = 404


class AccountLocked(_AccountMessage):
    """Indicates that the account is locked."""

    STATUS = 423


class AccountCreated(_AccountMessage):
    """Indicates that the account has been created."""

    STATUS = 201


class AccountDeleted(_AccountMessage):
    """Indicates that the account has been deleted."""

    STATUS = 200


class AccountPatched(_AccountMessage):
    """Indicates that the account has been patched."""

    STATUS = 200


class NotAuthorized(_AccountMessage):
    """Indicates that the an account is not
    authorized to perform the respective action.
    """

    STATUS = 403


class AccountExists(_AccountMessage):
    """Indicates that the respective account already exists."""

    STATUS = 409


class AccountsExhausted(_AccountMessage):
    """Indicates that the respective customer has
    exhauseted their respective account quota.
    """

    STATUS = 402


class PasswordTooShort(_AccountMessage):
    """Indicates that the provided password is too short."""

    STATUS = 415
```

The respective locales in `account.ini`:

```
[NoAccountSpecified]
de_DE = Kein Benutzerkonto angegeben.
en_US = No account specified.

[NoSuchAccount]
de_DE = Benutzerkonto nicht gefunden.
en_US = No such account.

[AccountLocked]
de_DE = Account gesperrt.
en_US = Account locked.

[AccountCreated]
de_DE = Account erstellt.
en_US = Account created.

[AccountDeleted]
de_DE = Account gelöscht.
en_US = Account deleted.

[AccountPatched]
de_DE = Account geändert.
en_US = Account patched.

[NotAuthorized]
de_DE = Zugriff verweigert.
en_US = Not authorized.

[AccountExists]
de_DE = Account existiert bereits.
en_US = Account already exists.

[AccountsExhausted]
de_DE = Maximale Anzahl an Accounts erreicht.
en_US = Account quota exhausted.

[PasswordTooShort]
de_DE = Das angegebene Passwort ist zu kurz.
en_US = The provided password is too short.
```

I'd like to get feedback on possible implementation optimizations.

Comment: Any reason not to use [`gettext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html)?

Comment: Didn't know that library until now. I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are somewhat reinventing [`gettext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html). So if your system allows it, you could use it instead.

You would need to change your `api.py` to:

```
"""HIS web API messages."""

import gettext

from flask import request
from wsgilib import JSON

__all__ = ['LanguageNotFound', 'Message']


class LanguageNotFound(Exception):
    """Indicates that the respective language could not be found."""

    def __init__(self, lang):
        """Sets the respective language."""
        super().__init__(lang)
        self.lang = lang


def get_translation(domain, language):
    """Create translation function for the given domain.mo files. The
    files are searched for in /etc/his.d/locales/.

    Returns a couple of functions: the first one to translate strings
    and the second one to translate pluralized strings.
    """
    locales_dir = '/etc/his.d/locales'
    try:
        translation = gettext.translation(domain, locales_dir, [language])
    except OSError as e:
        raise LanguageNotFound(language) from e
    else:
        return translation.gettext, translation.ngettext


class Message(JSON):
    """Messages returned by the respective web application."""

    STATUS = 200
    DOMAIN = 'his'

    def __init__(self, *data, status=None, **fields):
        """Initializes the message."""
        language = request.args.get('lang', 'de_DE')
        translate, _ = get_translation(self.DOMAIN, language)

        message = translate(self.__class__.__name__)

        if status is None:
            status = self.STATUS

        if data:
            message = message.format(*data)

        dictionary = {'message': message}
        dictionary.update(fields)
        super().__init__(dictionary, status=status)
```

And then, the only change needed to your various consumers would be to change the `LOCALES` class attribute to a `DOMAIN` one. *e.g.*:

```
class _AccountMessage(Message):
    """Abstract common account message."""

    DOMAIN = 'account'
```

But provided that all your `api` consumers are in their own module, which is not the `__main__` one, you can simplify further and remove the need for the base class such as `_AccountMessage`:

```
class Message(JSON):
    """Messages returned by the respective web application."""

    STATUS = 200

    def __init__(self, *data, status=None, **fields):
        """Initializes the message."""
        language = request.args.get('lang', 'de_DE')
        translate, _ = get_translation(self.__module__, language)

        message = translate(self.__class__.__name__)

        if status is None:
            status = self.STATUS

        if data:
            message = message.format(*data)

        dictionary = {'message': message}
        dictionary.update(fields)
        super().__init__(dictionary, status=status)
```

and then all your public messages could derive directly from `Message`. *e.g.*:

```
class NoAccountSpecified(Message):
    """Indicates that no account has been specified."""

    STATUS = 406
```

---

Now to use this API, you’ll have to conform to `gettext` specifications. First of all, you’ll need to gather language directories under your locales directory. For instance:

```
/etc/his.d/locales/de/LC_MESSAGES
/etc/his.d/locales/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES
/etc/his.d/locales/en/LC_MESSAGES
/etc/his.d/locales/en_US/LC_MESSAGES
```

I recommend having the generic language as a fallback to the specific region. Symbolic links can help remove redundancies so `de_DE` could be a symbolic link to `de` for instance.

Next you’ll have to put the domains inside each locale folder. Judging by your example, you’ll at least need an `account.mo` in each folder. To do so, prepare the translation file somewhat similarly to your `.ini` files as `.po` files. *e.g.* for `account.po`:

```
# Translations template for PROJECT.
# Copyright (C) 2016 ORGANIZATION
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PROJECT project.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, 2016.
#
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PROJECT VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: EMAIL@ADDRESS\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2018-20-06 22:14+0100\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Generated-By: Hand\n"

#: account.py:18
msgid "NoAccountSpecified"
msgstr "No account specified."

#: account.py:24
msgid "NoSuchAccount"
msgstr "No such account."

#: etc…
```

Then `account.po` need to be copied for each targeted locale and the `msgstr` need to be translated. Then each `.po` need to be converted to a `.mo` [using the `msgfmt` utility](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#internationalizing-your-programs-and-modules):

```sh
$ cd /etc/his.d/locales/de/LC_LOCALES
$ msgfmt account.po
```

---

Also note that since you might change language frequently, it may be a good idea to [load each language at startup and switch language on the fly](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#changing-languages-on-the-fly).

Or a [simple cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) could do:

```
@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def get_translation(domain, language):
    """Create translation function for the given domain.mo files. The
    files are searched for in /etc/his.d/locales/.

    Returns a couple of functions: the first one to translate strings
    and the second one to translate pluralized strings.
    """
    locales_dir = '/etc/his.d/locales'
    try:
        translation = gettext.translation(domain, locales_dir, [language])
    except OSError as e:
        raise LanguageNotFound(language) from e
    else:
        return translation.gettext, translation.ngettext
```